# How to implement jsp code in android?

Tags: java, android, jsp

I have a webpage which asks for username,password and there is a log in button. Log in button uses jsp function as follows

```
function submitData(){ 
            document.getElementById('txtSN').value=document.getElementById('txtRegNumber').value;
            document.getElementById('txtPD').value=document.getElementById('txtPwd').value;
            if(document.getElementById('txtSN').value == '' || document.getElementById('txtSN').length == 0) {
                alert(' Please Enter Student Register No/Studen ID');
                document.getElementById('txtSN').focus();
                return false;
            }

            if(document.getElementById('txtPD').value == '' || document.getElementById('txtPD').length == 0) {
                alert(' Please Enter Password');
                document.getElementById('txtPD').focus();
                return false;
            }
             if(document.getElementById('txtverifycode').value == '' || document.getElementById('txtverifycode').length == 0) {
                alert(' Please Enter Verification Code');
                document.getElementById('txtverifycode').focus();
                return false;
            }

            document.getElementById('txtPA').value=1;
            document.getElementById('txtRegNumber').value="iamalsouser";
            document.getElementById('txtPwd').value="thanksandregards";
            document.getElementById('frmStudentMain').action="youLogin.jsp";
            document.getElementById('frmStudentMain').submit();
        }
```

Can I use the above code in android. That is I will create two `EditText` for username and password; and I am going to create a function which is going to use above jsp code. What my question is, Is it possible to use jsp code for buttons in android?? Whether I want to convert the jsp code to java??
Actually I am newbie. If my question doesn't sounds good I am sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to explain because your snippet is not actually a jsp code but it is javascript function.

Regarding jsp implementation in android is,

JSP can't be implemented in Android. As JSP is build up using scriptlets and scripting tags which is deployed on server only. Server renders that jsp page whenever any request from client came. As a result it will convert data to pure HTML code and server to requester.
So, that is not at all possible to do on mobile.

But yes, if you want pure HTML to be display on android that can be possible using Web components of android. You can ajax call (in a way services) to server through it, get result (XML or JSON response), and render it back to your required view using JQuery or pure Javascript.

Comment: Actually i want to create an android app for my university in which students can check their attendance. Students will enter username and password and click the submit button and their profile will be displayed. Submit button has this jsp function. So I cant create a button which invokes this function right??

Comment: is there any other way to access the website by android button??